# Webpack EnvironmentPlugin doesn't see env variables when run with `docker-compose build`

Tags: docker, webpack, environment-variables

If I run the same task outside the docker it works well, it sees correct env variables from .env file webpack builds correctly, but not in docker. (although I can see env variables in Docker container inspect panel and they are used well in other containers tasks, for example mongo uses env variables to start replica)

Env file:

```js
DATABASE_URL="mongodb://root:prisma@mongo:27018/bookmeon?authSource=admin"

MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=prisma
MONGO_REPLICA_HOST=mongo
MONGO_REPLICA_PORT=27018

AUTH0_CLIENT_ID=123
AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET=456
AUTH0_DOMAIN=789
```

docker-compose.yml:

```js
name: bookmeon

# For connection urls to the following instances, see
# https://github.com/prisma/prisma/blob/main/TESTING.md#environment-variables
services:
  # Replica Set (required for Prisma Client)
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    build:
      dockerfile: ./docker/mongo.Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '27018:27018'
  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      dockerfile: ./docker/app.Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '1337:1337'
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  scratch:
    container_name: scratch
    build:
      dockerfile: ./docker/scratch.Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env
```

app.dockerfile:

```js
###################
# base
###################
FROM node:20.5.1-alpine3.18 As base
RUN apk add openssl1.1-compat
RUN apk add musl

RUN npm i -g pnpm

###################
# deps install
###################

FROM base As deps

WORKDIR /my

COPY --chown=node:node ./package.json .

RUN npm i

###################
# build
###################

FROM base As build

WORKDIR /my

COPY --chown=node:node --from=deps ./my/. .
COPY --chown=node:node ./tsconfig* .
COPY --chown=node:node ./webpack.js .

COPY --chown=node:node ./prisma ./prisma
COPY --chown=node:node ./src ./src
COPY --chown=node:node ./aps ./aps

RUN pnpm exec prisma generate
RUN pnpm run build
RUN pnpm run fe-build

USER node

ENTRYPOINT node dist/main.js; /
```

Webpack environment plugin usage:

```js
const plugins = [
  new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin([
    'CLOUDINARY_BUCKET',
    'AUTH0_CLIENT_ID',
    'AUTH0_DOMAIN',
    'NODE_ENV'
  ]),
///....
```

package.json tasks:

```js
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "NODE_ENV=development npx webpack serve --port=1338 -c ./webpack.js",  
    "fe-build": "npx webpack -c ./webpack.js",
    "build": "nest build",
```

Error:

```js
4.005 adding webpack development plugins
28.15 91 assets
28.15 2689 modules
28.15 
28.15 WARNING in DefinePlugin
28.15 Conflicting values for 'process.env.NODE_ENV'
28.15 
28.15 1 WARNING in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
28.15 
28.15 ERROR in EnvironmentPlugin - AUTH0_CLIENT_ID environment variable is undefined.
28.15 
28.15 You can pass an object with default values to suppress this warning.
28.15 See https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin for example.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so problem was because build phase has no access to .env file.

I had to add special section to docker-compose.yml that picks env variables, and mark what ARGS are used in app.dockerfile

docker-compose.yml addition:

```js
  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      dockerfile: ./docker/app.Dockerfile
      args:
        - NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
        - AUTH0_CLIENT_ID=${AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}
        - AUTH0_DOMAIN=${AUTH0_DOMAIN}
        - CLOUDINARY_BUCKET=${CLOUDINARY_BUCKET}
```

app.dockerfile addition:

```js
ARG NODE_ENV
ARG AUTH0_CLIENT_ID
ARG AUTH0_DOMAIN
ARG CLOUDINARY_BUCKET
```